# Is it possible to map control forward-slash with vim

Tags: vim, nnoremap

Hey wondering if it is possible to map control + forward-slash in vim. The mapping would be for normal mode if that makes a difference.

Have tried `<c-/>` but that didn't work.

Tried looking at the `:help keycodes` docs but was unable to understand if it was possible

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weirdly, you need to use <C-_> for control + forward-slash to work.